# Script, bot, automation

Tags: automation, bots, chat

I would like to make a script, that with a random time frame between 5 - 20 minutes write a text.

Its for a chat.

Additional, every hour you have been online, there is a pop up box, that appears random places. You have to click ok, otherwise you get kicked off the chat.

Is that possible to make?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Is it something easily made? As in, could you help me 